# All Subviews got disabled in ViewController Scene

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, subviews

I'm experiencing a weird problem in my storyboard. I can't found any of my subviews in my view controller (subviews of uiview) and at the same time all the them got disabled there in view controller scene. But if I run the project in simulator everything is working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `xcode 6.0`, please update you `xcode` to the latest version as there was a bug in xcode 6.0 that whenever you `resize` a `control` in a `viewController`, all the `controls` of that `viewController` changes its `height` and `width` to `0`. Meanwhile you can change you controls `dimensions` from the `Size inspector` in the right hand side rather that doing it by clicking and dragging the control to avoid this problem. I hope this helps you.